# Is it somehow possible to sync data on two mobiles phones

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, sync, 2.1-eclair

I am using a Samsung Galaxy S (running Android 2.1) mobile phone and am thinking (only thinking mind you) of bying a Samsung Galaxy tablet (this one running Android 2.2).

I am wondering: is it somehow **possible to sync the data used by programs on these two devices** so that software (like the marvelous Book catalogue) can be installed twice with the possiblity to copy the databases used by these program to both mobiles/tablets ?

Preferably by copying them over using WiFi or so.

Comment: Can you host the sql dbs in dropbox or somewhere else online?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i've one found so far paid solution, but there is a 30 day trial to check it out.
http://www.rerware.com/Android/; android app myBackup; you can backup data and apps, both online and on sd

Answer (score 0):

Don't know which book reader you're planning to use, but the Kindle app automatically syncs your progress through books, along with any notes and annotations you've made between devices and platforms (via its proprietary Whispersync service), and also lets you download the same books onto every device (as long as you sign in wit the same account).

Comment: @GA Thrawn: It's not a book reader I am talking about, it's a book catalogue program which I use to catalogue my library. This uses the sql database on my phone. It would be great if I could sync these databases between two devices. Although the question is a general one. I am a developer for Windows, working on 3 pc's, and I have a complete system set up of making sure my development environment and sources are exactly the same on all three pc's. From a user point of view, I think this should be possible in Android too (to sync databases and so on).

Answer (score 0):

If you setup both devices to use the same account(s) (for example the same Google account for the Google apps), then they should both synchronize with that account and thus indirectly with each other.

Theoretically there could be third party apps and accounts that tie their account to a specific device, but I can't say if these actually exist.